# error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘int getmaxy(const WINDOW*)’

Tags: graphics, c++

I'm trying to run the following program on my Ubuntu machine, adapted from [this program](https://bedeveloper.wordpress.com/a-c-to-program-to-show-2d-bouncing-ball/), using [libgraph](https://github.com/KhalilSawant/libgraph) to provide support for the BGI functions:

```c
#include <graphics.h>
#include <curses.h>
int main()
{
    int gd = DETECT, gm, i;
    initgraph(&gd, &gm, NULL);
    int x,y=0,j,t=400,c=1;
    setcolor(RED);
    setlinestyle(0,0,1);
    for(x=40;x<602;x++)
    {
        cleardevice();
        circle(x,y,20);
        floodfill(x,y,YELLOW);
        delay(40);
        if(y>=400)
        {
            c=0;
            t-=20;
        }
        if(y<=(400-t))
            c=1;
        y=y+(c?15:-15);
    }
    getch();
}
```

It's supposed to output a bouncing ball. But when I compile it I'm getting the following error:

```
error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘int getmaxx(const WINDOW*)’
error: conflicting declaration of C function ‘int getmaxy(const WINDOW*)’
```

I searched all over the internet but still not able to resolve the error. Can someone help me, please?

Comment: Where did you find the program? It looks like a BGI program for DOS, but the `curses.h` include doesn’t fit that.

Comment: I get the program from [here](https://bedeveloper.wordpress.com/a-c-to-program-to-show-2d-bouncing-ball/)

Comment: I  have already installed libgraph package and I'm able to run graphics functions on my machine. But when I tried to run the above code then it gives me error. I've already seen this error a few times before but not able to figure out the mistake.

Comment: Please don't downvote the answer as I'm frustrated now b'cause of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend [SDL_bgi](http://libxbgi.sourceforge.net/) for this kind of conversion, it seems better-maintained than libgraph. Using that, you need to remove the `#include <curses.h>` line (which is causing the conflicting declarations), and build with

```
gcc bounce.c -lSDL_bgi $(pkg-config --libs sdl2) -o bounce
```

Comment: I got the error : ```error: ‘SOLID_FILL’ was not declared in this scope```    
```note: suggested alternative: ‘SOLID_LINE’```    
```error: ‘setfillstyle’ was not declared in this scope```    
```suggested alternative: ‘setlinestyle’
```